# Adding an icon to my finished application

Tags: c#, icons

What's the proper way to add an icon to my application? I mean to the actual physical .exe file.

Comment: MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right click your project (the one that is compiled to an exe), choose Properties, under the Application Tab, in the "Icon and manifest" section, change your icon.