# Custom icon that opens URL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I've only used Visual Studio a handful of times.

Can I make an executable with a custom icon that strictly opens a URL in a web browser?

I am assuming Visual Studio will be the best tool to help me achieve this, although I am open to better options.

It has to have a custom icon and be a stand alone file.

Thanks.

Comment: Using Visual Studio seems a bit overkill to me. Why not just create a simple BAT file and convert it to exe to add an icon?

Comment: I didn't realize you could convert bat to exe. I will look into this

Comment: If you have access to Visual Studio then that is better than BAT2EXE options. The source code allows for improvements in case you are interested to do this in the future and no dependency on BAT2EXE compatibility on your platforms (e.g. C#/C++ code will easily work on linux but a BAT file will be a lot more work to port, or will require two stones to kill that bird).

Answer (score 3):

if you don't need it to be an executable you could quickly create a windows shortcut.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140443

You can personalize the icon too.

As PrashantGupta has pointed out you can only use a subsets of windows icons if you want it to be a single file.

Comment: For a truly user-made icon a shortcut be more than one standalone file.

Comment: @PrashantGupta can you please explain why?

Comment: @MiserableVariable because the icons are not embeded in the shortcut but linked from known dll,exe,ico files

Comment: @MiserableVariable: What giammin said, the icons are in separate files referenced by the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

Just write a single line console app with this as your code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://my.url.com");
```

You can configure an icon from within visual studio easily too.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, did I get this right: You need an EXE with custom icon and launches a URL?

If you choose C# as your development language the following code will achieve what you want:

```
namespace URLLauncher
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/");
      }
   }
}
```

Changing the icon is also quite straightforward in visual studio as well. See this: [Adding an icon to my finished application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297375/adding-an-icon-to-my-finished-application)

Also try not to make your application a "Console" application as that will pop up a "black console window" when you launch the app if you need a double-click interface from the user (which I infer from your wanting an ICON).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go the C++ route, passing a URL to the `ShellExecute` function will let you launch a website using the user's preferred browser.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816

And you don't really need anything from the C or C++ runtime for this, so compile with `/NODEFAULTLIB` use the `/ENTRYPOINT` linker option to skip all that, make your executable truly tiny, and have very few dependencies (meaning none that aren't included in every version of Windows since 95).  It'll start faster too, not needing to run .NET or any library initialization code.

Add your icon in the usual way using the Resource Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

**Solves the problem, not necessarily with the requested tool**

While we are at-it, so to speak, I thought someone must have invented this wheel before, so if you are not interested in any development what-so-ever (check licenses before use tho), here are some online tools to do what you want:

[Web shortcut producer](http://www.rw-designer.com/make-shortcut-icon)

Remember to scan the EXE for for malware. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio route has a lot of advantages and will work for this situation.  Although, it is overkill for the project I am working on.

I have chosen to go with this solution:

Build a .bat file with the command:

```
start http://www.google.com
```

Then use a bat to exe converter which allows icon assignment.

Worked like a charm and quick.